# Aurelia: Trigger update on one custom element when a value in another custom element changes?

Tags: aurelia

I've just recently asked a question ( [Refreshing i18n translated string interpolated values in Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489609/refreshing-i18n-translated-string-interpolated-values-in-aurelia) ) regarding how to refresh i18n string interpolated values when a select input field (with language ids) changes. I received a great answer, however now I realized that there was another requirement.

It's not only string interpolated values that needs to be refreshed.

In my page-specific templates I have some select fields (custom elements), which gets their option values from injecting a "service" class. That service is responsible for doing the http fetch request, and returning a promise to the select field (custom element).

Now here's the problem. When the global (language) select field from my site-wide nav-bar custom element changes, and i18n refreshing happens using the notification approach proposed in the link above. How would I then also re-fetch my different select input custom elements inside the template, but with the new language id from the language select in the nav-bar?

The only solution I know so far is to do window.location (router.navigate(sameroute) didn't trigger a refresh) and refresh the current page whenever the language select changes, however that's obviously not a great way to handle this.

I'll try to see if I can put together a plunkr, since all this may sound a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

@chrismbeckett from in https://gitter.im/Aurelia/Discuss gave me this hint:

> "For those types of inter-component syncs, use the EventAggregator.
>   Pub a 'lang-changed' event and let any component do what it needs to
>   update itself"

So in nav-bar.js i did this:

```
let payload = { 'lngId': this.appLngId};
this.eventAggregator.publish('lang_changed', payload);
```

and in the custom element which were to be refreshed I put this inside the attached() function:

```
this.eventAggregator.subscribe('lang_changed', payload => {
    alert(payload.lngId)
    self.myTodosService.getMyTodos(payload.lngId);
    .then(function(data){
        self.myTodos = data;
    })
});
```